# Getting "cannot find symbol" error with reader.nextLine()

Tags: java, oop, compiler-errors

Here is my code (it is code to reverse a given string)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReversingName {
    public static String reverse(String text) {
    // write your code here
    int strlenght= text.length();
    int i=1;
    String str= "";
    while (i<=strlenght){
        char test= text.charAt(strlenght-1);
        str=str+test;
    }
    return str;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Type in your text: ");
    String text = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("In reverse order: " + reverse(text));
}
}
```

But I cannot take in input because when I try to take the string input I get a "cannot find symbol error" even though I have clearly defined the variable "text".

This question is from MOOC.fi's Java OOP course, and can be found here (question 52, if it helps): https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part1/week-3/

Comment: Where is "reader" defined?

Comment: Provide full error stacktrace if any.

Comment: Not directly to your question but `System.out.println(new StringBuilder("abc").reverse().toString());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reader` is never declared. From the looks of things, it seems as though it's supposed to be a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); // Declare and initialize reader
    System.out.print("Type in your text: ");
    String text = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println("In reverse order: " + reverse(text));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512451/getting-cannot-find-symbol-error-with-reader-nextline/56512478#56512478) said you never created `reader`.

Your while loop also wont work properly and will never stop running.  Adding `strlenght--` at the end of it should make it work properly.

Comment: Yes, the loop has errors, but I was focused on getting the input part, will correct the loop now that that is sorted. Thanks